# Set cookie on page; is it available to all resources loaded from that page?

Tags: http, cookies

Say my application returns a Set-Cookie header with an HTML page. That page loads some images, JavaScript files, etc.

Is it guaranteed that the new cookie will be sent in the requests for these resources? Or could this be a race condition, or browser-dependent?

Answer (score 1):

The cookie will be sent in all requests to the same domain that set the cookie. This is why it's often recommended to host static content on a separate subdomain to avoid he overhead added by these cookies.